# What creates the Global Dipole Magnetic Field in the Sun?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, astronomy, sun, convection

[image]

I understand that the Sun undergoes convection and with rotation, the convective cells have a helical motion because of the Coriolis Force. My confusion comes from the fact that via the right-hand rule, wouldn't the magnetic field lines in the southern hemisphere cancel the ones from the northern hemisphere? Essentially, can you explain the generated global dipole field given this picture? How do individual cells lead to a large-scale field? Everyone always asserts that the Sun has a dipole field... but HOW?